# Почему так тормозит XCODE?

Tags: xcode

После перехода на xcode 9 и swift 4, xcode начал дико тормозить, при переходе из файла в файл подсветка кода просто пропадает.(Лечу простым перезапуском xcode) При вводе текста иногда просто зависает, смотря на загруженность процессора 80 процентов  и 14г оперативки из 16. Почему так сильно жрет?

В obj-c шных проектах такого не было, в проекте использую сториборды и xib, но сториборды не перегружены. Экранов примерно 20 и всего 3 библиотекы.

Мог бы думать что проблема в компьютере но  у меня макбук конецк 2015 и я бы не сказал что он слабый. В интрерфейс билдерах как ни странно ничего не лагает!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кто-то сталкивался подскажите пожалуйста. Буду очень признателен)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Некоторые советы может быть и вредные, некоторые возможно плацебо, но мне помогает.

1. Следите в Activity monitor за SoureKitService. Порой он начинает активно выжирать память:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смело его прибивайте. Как прибьете - в Xcode отпадет подсветка на доли секунд, но затем все восстановится и нормально будет работать автокомплит.

2. В File -> Project(Workspace) Settings выберите New Build System:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого у меня значительно возросла скорость сборки и стало меньше проблем при работе в Xcode (особенно в проектах с подами и миксом Objective-C + Swift)

3. Периодически делайте чистку сочетанием Cmd-Opt-Shift-K
4. Опционально. Жесткий вариант п.3: по пути из п.2 выберите не дефолтную папку для Derived Data (для удобства):

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И периодически вручную очищайте ее.

На старичке Mac mini 2011 с i5 сразу оживает Xcode.

Comment: Спасибо большое. После смены Build System, вообще вся подсветка исчезла) Но вот с драйвд дата вроде помогло!